# How to move the front image upward and back image downward on click ?, With jQuery or Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Suppose there are Two Circular images, front one completely covers the back one. When I click on front image, I want it to move upward and  back image move downward and stops at each other's round edges. A second click will make the front image cover the back one.

Comment: Are you looking to bring one element to the front and send the other to the back, or just position one beneath the other?

Comment: just want to position the front image upward & back image downward.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to move an element above or below another element, you can use `insertBefore` and `insertAfter`:

```
$("#div1").insertAfter($("#div2"));
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Eb3cv/

Answer (score 0):

Sample css

```
.above{position:absolute;z-index:2}
.under{position:absolute;z-index:3}
.container{position:relative;z-index:1}
```

Sample Objects

```
<div class="container">  
<img id="img1" class="above" src="..." />
<img id="img2" class="under" src="..." />
</div>
```

Sample JQuery

```
$('img').click(function(){

 $('#img1').toggleClass('above');
 $('#img1').toggleClass('under');
 $('#img2').toggleClass('above');
 $('#img2').toggleClass('under');

});
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/p95NE/10/)

Comment: Like, Front image & Back image Slips "Move" from their Common places, to Upward & Downward Respectively.

Comment: If It's works for you accept the answer to remove it from unsanswered list. Cheers